# vim: mark wrapped line with a plus

Tags: vim

In [mutt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_%28e-mail_client%29), when I open a message , it is opened with *vim*. The lines longer that the screen width are wrapped and a small red "plus" is displayed at the beginning of the wrapped line. What *vim* command enables that?

Unwrapped:

```
|<------ screen width -------->|                                             
very long line very long line very long line ...
```

Wrapped with "plus":

```
|<------ screen width -------->|                                             
very long line very long line                                                
+very long line very long line                                               
+very long line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 set showbreak=+
 set wrap
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless *mutt* fiddles with the actual text, it's probably

```
:set wrap
:set showbreak=+
```

The red highlighting would then come from the `@<hlgroupname>` flag in `:set highlight?`.

Except `'wrap'`, these are global settings, so either your Vim has these non-default configurations somewhere, or it is explicitly set by mutt when it invokes Vim.

Answer (score 2):

See `:help showbreak`. You can change the string used to prepend wrapped lines.